# How to assign default landscape image for iphone in xcode4

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have created a universal app and I want to display a default image. I assigned all images to the properties we can set in xcode4. But I did not get any property where I can set iphone landscape image. and even where to set iphone-retina landscape image. I searched on web and i found that I should append `-landscape`  to default image. I did that but does not worked. can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have a single default image for iPhone per resolution. Currently that's one for retina and one for older screens. This image must always be portrait even if your app launches in landscape only in which case you would create a landscape default image and rotate it 90 degrees to be portrait.

Comment: can i assign 2 default images?

Comment: No, only one for retina and one for classic. To do it in Xcode 4, select your project in the left pane, select target and drag & drop the images to placeholders.

Comment: Yes I did that. So only portrait image will be displayed as i have assigned portrait image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html:

In iOS 3.2 and later, an iPad application can provide both landscape and portrait versions of its launch images. Each orientation-specific launch image must include a special modifier string in its filename. The format for orientation-specific launch image filenames is as follows:

`<basename><orientation_modifier><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png`

E.g. setting the image for landscape left: `-LandscapeLeft`: Specifies a left-oriented landscape version of the launch image. A file with this modifier takes precedence over a file with the -Landscape modifier for this specific orientation.